# responsive filemanager images upload

Tags: php, image-uploading, responsive-filemanager

I can't upload images in "Responsive File Manager", it says not enough memory, I'm using LAMP on Ubuntu 16.04. But it can upload PDF files successfully, I don't know the reason why!, server uploading size = 8MB in both php.ini and the file manager config.php file